Wrong version of Tanstack Query DevTools is showing
I've installed the latest version (v5) of the devtools by using the following command
$ npm i @tanstack/react-query-devtools
While I expected a palm tree icon for opening the tools, my browser is showing a flower and the menu itself looks like an older version, since there are fewer actions possible:

I believe in the latest version it should look something like this:

Since I haven't used the devtools before, I don't really know which version is showing and why.
I checked the package.json:
"dependencies": {
"@tanstack/react-query": "^5.45.0",
"@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.45.0",
},


"devDependencies": {
"@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query": "^5.43.1",
}

I might have somehow installed a different version before, but I am not sure about that and even if that would have been the case, a newer version would have overwritten the older one right?

Solved.
Deleted 'react-query' from package.json since it was used instead of '@tanstack/react-query' and contained an older version.
